# Why would it take so great distance for an object to have the acceleration due to gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity

Let's suppose that in a certain reference frame, a hyperbolic coordinate is used, i.e. $(x,t)=(r\cosh \omega, r \sinh \omega)$. On each hyperbola $r=R$, where $R>0$ is a constant, the proper acceleration is constant and the value of the proper acceleration is given by $\frac{c^2}{R}$.

Then for an object under acceleration due to gravity, $R=\frac{c^2}{g}$, which is a very large distance.

My question is: why would it happen that the distance is so large, and what does $R$ physically mean?

**Remark**: It was the following video (Prof. Susskind's lecture) that leads to the question risen. He started the relevant discussion in 1:08:34.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdnLcYNdTzE

Comment: Here is the WP article on Rindler coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates . It can be helpful to people reading the question if they don't have to watch a video to get the information they need about the question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you start from rest in a certain frame of reference described by the Minkowski coordinates $(t,x)$. From that point on, you maintain a proper acceleration in the positive $x$ direction, which we call "right." At some distance on your left, there is an event horizon. If a photon traveling to the right is emitted from the horizon, starting at the same time you started, it will never catch up with you, although it will asymptotically approach you. The large distance $R$ is the distance between your starting point and the horizon. The reason it's so large is that you will need a very large head start so that by accelerating at $g$ you can keep the photon from catching up.